# More than 4 partitions with Ubuntu & Windows Dual Boot

Tags: partition

I would like to install Windows 10 & Ubuntu on my PC. I have done this before on my laptop however my PC is giving me issues. On my PC I have created 2 partitions on Windows, and 2 partitions on Linux, root and home. The system will not let me create a fifth partition for swap because it says it's limited to 4 partitions. How can I avoid this limitation? I am new to  so a thorough answer is appreciated.

Comment: Are you willing to start from fresh? installing windows and then ubuntu again... My question is because both Windows 10 and Ubuntu support GPT disks, and GPT does not have the 4 partition limitation

Comment: Other option is to delete one of your primary partitions and create a logical one, inside the logical partition can reside several extended partitions

Comment: Yes i want to start fresh, i'm just doing backup right now and want to install windows and then ubuntu. Where can i make a logical partition? Can i install Windows and let space for Ubuntu, then in windows with some program change that partition on logical and then install ubuntu on this partition?

Answer (score 2):

> The system will not let me create a fifth partition for swap because it says it's limited to 4 partitions. How can I avoid this limitation?

The MBR supports up to 4 **primary partitions**. To avoid this limitation you need to use one of the primary partitions as an **extended partition**.

Also you can convert your disk to [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (GPT), you will be allowed to create 128 partitions.

On GPT the Windows 10 can boot only with EFI firmware. Linux should boot Legacy and EFI.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu installer, when asked how much space do you want for your ubuntu system, choose the option below the slider that says Advanced partitioning, there you will be presented with a tree view of the partition table outlining your already existing partitions for windows, there you must resize one of the windows partitions if you didn't leave any unpartitioned space for ubuntu, to resize just select the last partition and click the edit button, in the edit window just reduce the size leaving the desired space for ubuntu and don't change anything else.

After that in the tree view there will be a free space option in the list, select that and click the '+' button, input the desired size (take in mind the space needed for the home and swap partitions and don't use all the space), select the logical radio button and in the 'Mount point' option select '/' (root) from the dropdown and click OK.

Repeat the previous step for the home partition but select '/home' from the dropdown, and again for swap.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the logical partition instead of primary. Your problem is solved. You can do this in 2 ways:

1) Make your / root as primary and home and swap as logical.

2)or make everything logical.

Comment: The OP asked for “a thorough answer”.   Please provide details — what steps should the user take?    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.